# cakephp Associations Delete not working

Tags: cakephp

I have a table of files and a table of permissions. The idea is that the user can assign permissions to other users to allow them to read, edit, etc. I set up an association so that the files, which I call workspaces, have many permissions. Here is the declaration in the workspaces model linking the permissions model

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Permission' => array(
        'className' => 'Permission',
        'foreignKey'=> 'workspace_id',
        'dependent' => true
    )
);
```

The problem is that when I go to delete a file, I get an error.

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Permission.id' in 'field list'
SQL Query: SELECT `Permission`.`id` FROM `cadwolfc_workspaces`.`permissions` AS `Permission` WHERE `Permission`.`workspace_id` = 71
```

Why is cakephp looking for an id parameter in the permissions table when I have clearly defined the workspace_id as the foreign key? I had assumed that by linking the models and then deleting a workspace, the associated permissions would be deleted. That is what I am trying to do here. I don't understand why a select query is being executed when a delete query is what is needed?

Update: The call to delete the workspace item is done through an ajax call by passing the id of the workspace. I have confirmed that $fileid is the correct number.

```
$this->Workspace->delete($fileid);
```

Update 2: When I add a column to the permissions table titled 'id' add make its value the appropriate number, then the delete call works fine and all items are deleted. Why is this?

Comment: show us your delete query please

Comment: Did you define foreign key in database table?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what that means to define a foreign key in the database table? The foreign key is defined in the model as 'workspace_id' and it indeed exists within the permissions table. However, the problem is that the code is looking for an id parameter in the permissions table instead of the defined workspace_id and I don't understand why.

Comment: I did not work a lot in cakephp combined with mysql but everything i did i did define i.e. to tables, made index on field and define foreign key on database level than defined it in cakephp model also I did not have those issues. You can google how to define index-es in phpmyadmin if you are using mysql.

Comment: Show me the definition of the Workspace Model, including the filename you gave to that file